# How to get a django QuerySet of all ForeignKeys of all objects in a Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model (or actually 2 models, but the other is not that relevant)

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar,
        ...
    )
```

When I have a QuerySet of `Foo`:s, how do I get all the `Bar` instances that are referenced by that QuerySet?

Since I'm using MySQL, I can't do `.distinct(['bar'])`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
foo_queryset = Foo.objects.filter(attr=value)
referenced_bars = Bar.objects.filter(id__in=foo_queryset.values('bar_id'))
```

Comment: Here's a link to the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) field lookup in the docs.

Comment: I'm curious, how efficient is this and is there a way of doing it more efficiently?

Comment: @Algorithmatic - that's a very broad question, it depends on the database you are using, the data and indexes on that data. Running this on MySQL can be horrifically slow because MySQL is terrible at handling the subqueries that Django generates. To get around this issue you can perform 1 query to get the `bar_ids` and then pass this to the `__in` clause `Bar.objects.filter(id__in=set(foo_queryset.values('bar_id')))` obviously if you have a lot of `Foo` objects this can also be slow

Comment: It seems to me that it may not be a efficient solution. What if you have thousands of `bar_id`?

Answer (score 0):

```
bars = Bar.objects.filter(foo_set__attr=value)
```

Comment: Where does my `QuerySet` containing the relevant `Foo`s go in this?

Comment: I thought - and that thought might have been wrong - it would be the easiest to ignore the querset (one object less to care about). Instead apply the limits/filter of this initial qeryset directly to Bars. Basically, foo_set__attr=value is just a placeholder that you can extend to whatever you like to define the Foo's that you would like to use. Would that help or do you insist on using a separate Foo queryset?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `foo_queryset.bar_set.all()` to get all instances of your `Bar`

```
foo_queryset = Foo.objects.filter(attr=value)
referenced_bars = foo_queryset.bar_set.all()
```

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more details.