# Is there a way to get foreign key instance from the QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, psql

I trying to get the foreign key instance stored in the ***CandidateSkill*** model(In[5]) but want to avoid using loop.

I have tried `values()` it only return the actual `candidate_id(int)` stored in ***Candidate*** model and not the instance.

models.py

```py
class Candidate(models.Model):
    candidate_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False)

class CandidateSkill(models.Model):
    candidate_id = models.ForeignKey('hr.Candidate', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

Django Shell

```py
In [1]: from hr.models import CandidateSkill as cds

In [2]: a = cds.objects.filter(skill__icontains = 'py')

In [3]: a
Out[3]: <QuerySet [<CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (1)>, <CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (2)>, <CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (3)>, <CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (4)>, <CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (10)>]>

In [4]: a[0]
Out[4]: <CandidateSkill: CandidateSkill object (1)>

In [5]: a[0].candidate_id
Out[5]: <Candidate: Clayton Cote>
```

So I there a way to get only the foreign key instance and avoid using the loop.

Comment: Not sure If I understand, but maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600765/how-to-get-a-django-queryset-of-all-foreignkeys-of-all-objects-in-a-queryset/12600950#12600950)!.

Comment: In addition you can add a `def __str__` method in the candidate model inside a Meta class, so you will see their name, looks like you want the entire instance, but the name will help a bit for readability.

Comment: What do you mean by `looping`. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: totally unrelated but your `CandidateSkill.candidate_id` field should be named `CandidateSkill.candidate` - a `ForeignKey` field's value is the related model instance (so a `Candidate` instance here), not it's id. The ORM will take care of translating this to a `candidate_id` foreign key at the db schema level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get all Candidates that have a CandidateSkill containing the string 'py'? This should get what you want

```
Candidate.objects.filter(candidateskill__skill__icontains='py')
```